# How to know if someone clicked on your link and installed the linked app in the Play Store

Tags: android, facebook, google-play, click-tracking

When publishing a link to a mobile application on Facebook (Link to a Product Details Page on Play Store),
how can I see if someone clicked on my link and installed the linked app in the Play Store?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running an **ad campaign** on Facebook, you can view the amount of link clicks, app installs, and overall post interaction via Facebook Ad Manager.

(Somewhere around here: www.facebook.com/ads/manager/)

Unfortunately, Facebook requires you to add their own SDK to your application. If you don't want to do this, check out this page: https://developers.google.com/app-conversion-tracking/third-party-trackers/android#measure_installs

This ^^^ demonstrates how to identify "deep link" installs.